# Website security certificate page not shown

Tags: security, internet-explorer, certificate, ssl-certificate, security-warning

I access an https:// blackberry website for administration with two different pc, on pc1 appear the security certificate webpage where i can choose to close the webpage or continue (not recommended); on pc2 appear an error page "This page can’t be displayed", but i need that webpage to be shown (tested with all browsers already).

edit: i tried to save the website certificate from the pc1 and install it on pc2 but still the same error occurs

Comment: Please add more info (eg:- Browser,site). It depends on browser, what's the error on pc2?

Comment: in iexploer say simply This page can’t be displayed, while in Firefox:
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to xxxx.com. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Open command prompt, type `ping https://website.tld` and tell me the output.

Comment: ...could not find the host...

Comment: Its a problem with the server, not your PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: was because of a Windows Update Security Package KB3061518, after uninstalled and reboot the pc the website goes now.

Comment: Note by uninstalling this security update, you are leaving your computer vulnerable to an information disclosure attack. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3061518

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, After typing **about:config** in the url bar and clicking the check box "I'll be careful, I promise, that should display a screen listing preferences.

Click on the search line at the upper right and type or paste `tls` and then pause while the list is filtered.

If you scroll down, you should find and be able to find security.tls.version.min, right click on it and **Modify** it to set its value to **0**.

Refer [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*) for more.

**EDIT:-** You can try the below simple method.

Goto ***Menu***>Preferences>Advanced>Certificates> Uncheck the box that says *"Query OCSP responder servers to confirm the current validity of servers."*

Comment: changed, but i get always the same error

Comment: Try the edited answer!

Comment: as well doesn´t work

Comment: It may be a server problem.. can you tell me the site?